# How to add characters in sql between two strings?

Tags: oracle

I'd like to know is it possible to add characters between two or more string using `LPAD` in SQL example sentence  'The Cat Is Sleeping'

```
LPAD('string', number, '+')
```

expected results:

```
++++++The+++++Cat+++++++Is++++++Sleeping
```

pas :-amount of + above is just an example maybe the result will be different. I hope you can understand my question.

if you are willing give me the exact query
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a good candidate for doing a regex replacement with `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(input, '^| ', '+++++++') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

The output is:

```
+++++++The+++++++Cat+++++++Is+++++++Sleeping
```

### Demo

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'The Cat Is Sleeping' AS input FROM dual
)
```

Comment: what if i want to add different amount of stars for each word?

Comment: ...that's a different question, and not what you asked (or what was answered) `:-)`